# Обновление данных в адаптере ListView

Tags: android, c#, monodroid, xamarin

Здравствуйте! Есть чат на android в двух вариантах: групповой и личный. Есть такой адаптер который работает в обоих чатах:

```
    public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = this._bubbleList [position];
        var view = (convertView ??
                   this._context.LayoutInflater.Inflate (
                       Resource.Layout.bubble,
                       parent,
                       false)) as LinearLayout;

        TextView message = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.list_bubble_message);
        message.Text = item.message;
        if (item.left == false) {
            view.SetGravity (GravityFlags.Right);
            message.SetBackgroundResource (Resource.Drawable.mymessage);
        } else {
            view.SetGravity (GravityFlags.Left);
            message.SetBackgroundResource (Resource.Drawable.friendmessage);
        }

        return view;
    }
```

С групповым чатом все легко, все сообщения выводятся в один и тот же ListView, но в случае с личным чатом (тет-а-тет) есть проблема, при переходе от беседы с одним человеком, в беседу с другим, все сообщения из прошлой беседы показываются в новой. Как можно разделить эти List View, что бы для каждой беседы был свой. Все еще усложняет то, что зарание не известно сколько будет этих бесед у пользователя.

Comment: Кэп подсказыват, что при переходе от одного чата к другому неплохо было бы обновлять данные адаптера

Comment: Я понимаю, что нужно обновлять данные адаптера, но как лучше это сделать не дошло

Comment: а в чем проблема-то?

Comment: В том, что я не знаю как обновлять данные адаптера в личных сообщениях. P.S. Сообщения приходят в виде xml файла, в котором написаны id сообщения, отправитель и сам текст сообщения.

Comment: А может каждый чат делать отдельным Фрагментом? А в каждом Фрагменте свой ListView, свой Loader и свой Adapter?